# Issue with image from URL in UITableVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, uitableview

I'm noticing some weird behavior with my UITableView.

I want to display a thumbnail image in the TableViews ImageView. The image is on my clients server and the link to this image is fetched in a XML-file. Whenever I get the URL from my XML-Parser and try to display the image from that link in the ImageView I don't get the expected result. The TableViews ImageView stays empty.

```
NSString * imagePath = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imagelink"];

NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.imageView.image = image;


return cell;
```

However when I hardcode the URL in, it works just fine:

```
NSString * imagePath = @"http://www.test.com/test.jpg";

NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.imageView.image = image;


return cell;
```

This displays the image in the ImageView.

I already used NSLog to compare the URLs but I didn't notice any difference.
However when I do a string comparison the links seem to be different.

Is there any special encoding or something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you show an NSLog output of your "`imagePath`" from the first block of sample code?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",imagePath); gives back: http://picture.immobilienscout24.de/files/basic003/N/161/291/603/161291603-1.jpg

Its the same exact link, when I paste it in the browser it all works.

Comment: PS: there was meant to be a http:// before the link

Comment: still having trouble with this or did you solve it?